# How do I enter text in an alert textfield using Xcode UI Automation testing

Tags: ios, xcode, testing, uialertview, ios-ui-automation

This problem is really bugging me. Having read the official documentation, the book by Jonathan Penn and all the online tutorials I can find. I have built a really simple app to learn about UI Testing but am getting stumped at the first step. Its a todo list app. I click on the UIBarButtonItem button which displays a dialog with a UITextField and two button, OK and Cancel. Here is the IBAction.

```
@IBAction func showDialog(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    println("showDialog")
    var inputTextField: UITextField?
    var alert:UIAlertController
    alert = UIAlertController(title: "New Item", message: "Type item below", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Item name"  // need to choose correct keyboard and capitalise first letter of each word.
        inputTextField = textField
    })
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in
        if let itemName = inputTextField?.text {
            println(itemName)
            self.items.append(itemName)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }))
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I have tried to write a UI Automation test by recording then adding the alert handler but it won't work. Here is my testing script.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

UIALogger.logWarning('script started');

target.frontMostApp().navigationBar()￼￼.rightButton().tap();

UIATarget.onAlert = function onAlert(alert) {
    var title = alert.name();
    UIALogger.logWarning("Alert with title ’" + title + "’ encountered!");
    target.frontMostApp().keyboard().typeString("Cheese");
    alert.buttons()["OK"].tap();
    return true;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching I found the answer. The onAlert function simply returns `true` if we want to interact with the alert and `false` if we simply want to dismiss it.

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var app = target.frontMostApp();
var window = app.mainWindow();
window.navigationBar().rightButton().tap();

UIATarget.onAlert = function() {
    return true;
}

app.keyboard().typeString("Cheese");
app.alert().buttons()["OK"].tap();
```